# How to pass a variable into method to DELETE from SQLite DB - Python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am not sure why this isn't working. I am trying to delete an entry from the database I created. Here is sample of parts of the python code that is erroring out.

delete_domain = 'm.com'

```
sql.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists domains
(name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
clock CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
person TEXT,
reason TEXT);''')


def searchdb(name):
sql.execute("DELETE FROM domains WHERE name = name;", (name))
sql.commit() # Commit changes to the DB
print("Record successfully deleted")
cursor.close()
```

searchdb(delete_domain) # Testing method

ERROR below:

sql.execute("DELETE FROM domains WHERE name = name;", (name))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 5 supplied.

Comment: Change `(name))` to `(name,))` (with the comma) to make a tuple. Currently it's trying to unpack the characters of your string one-by-one. It expects an iterable, which a string is, so it ends up iterating the individual characters and looks for a placeholder to put them in your query string... but there's only 1 available.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I am not long getting that error but a new one appeared.

sql.execute("DELETE FROM domains WHERE name = name;" (name,))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: You're welcome. It's a really common issue, I was looking for the canonical dupe but got beaten to it.

Comment: Yes, because now you got rid of the comma after the query string. The fix is to add a comma only, you should not remove the comma between `WHERE name = name;"` and `(name,))`